# Is there a function identical to "IF" but defaults the 3rd argument to NULL?

Tags: mysql

Basically I want to do

```
IF(x>y,z,NULL)
```

But without having to specify the 3rd argument all the time. I'm going to be using this a lot and I want my queries to be a bit more readable. Is there a function that is basically identical to `IF` except the 3rd argument defaults to `NULL`?

Comment: The only alternative to IF() might be the CASE operator but if that's too many words, then I think IF() is your best choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** There is no function that meets your requirements.

<sup>I'm answering myself because no one wrote "no" in their answer.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE x WHEN 'y' THEN NULL ELSE x END
```

something like this?

Comment: No... trying to be *less* verbose, not *more* verbose.

Comment: That'll be handy for some other, unrelated enum-like cases though. +1

Answer (score 0):

there's this. but it is a bit more specific than what you asked for...

```
IFNULL(foo, 123)
```

it means this

```
IF(foo IS NULL, 123, foo)
```

Comment: Nope. Condition needs to be something like `x>0` or... whatever. Needs to be flexible, won't always be `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

There does exist a [`NULLIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) function, but its semantics are a bit different -- depending on the actual expressions `x` and `y` it might or might not work for you.

```
NULLIF (a, b)
```

returns `a` if `a != b`, and `null` if `a = b`.

Comment: @Mark: Bummer. AFAIK there's nothing else that fits your description.

Comment: "No" is an acceptable answer. Not the one that I was hoping for... but, still an answer.